# How do I enable free shipping in backend only (for order entry)

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

How do I enable free shipping as shipping method when we create order from admin panel ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Override

```
app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php
```

And add

```
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())) {
            return false;
        }
```

And set to active in backend

You can place the code in local if you dont want to overwrite the core

I can imagine that we add this as an extra option in backend settings and this way make it configurable.

Comment: NOw one needs to turn this into a simple extension that adds a config option to Freeshipping in settings (backend only yees/no). BUt this is above my programming skills

Comment: here ya go! and thanks for the clever idea. https://github.com/ryaan-anthony/Ip_Freeship

Answer (score 3):

While in payment methods it is possible to activate them with a flag only on frontend and also on backend (but not vice-versa), for shipping methods there are no such flags at all.

You could derive an own shipping method in a custom module and overwrite `getAllowedMethods()` to determine if the order is to be created in the frontend or in the backend,

A very simple workaround would be to create a free-shipping cart rule with a promo code that only you know. This then can be simply entered in the backend.

Comment: Thanks Alex, SOme remakrs, I came across this `code` public function  isAvailable($quote = null)
{
    return (parent::isAvailable($quote) && Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin());
}`code`

Comment: And promo code is not an option. Because then Magento doesnt allow another promotion code (for example discount) ---- as such, we have never got it to work

Answer (score 0):

You would make collectRates() return empty unless it's being invoked via admin. How to know if its invoked via admin, well you could set a registry value.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a free open source extension on GitHub for that: [Llian_FreeAdminShipping](https://github.com/Llian/FreeAdminShipping).